# Execute PHP script after mail server receives a mail

Tags: php, postfix-mta, dovecot

I am writing an application When email server received an email, to run PHP script in order to replace the mail "from address" with random generated email address as from address.

Basically, email server receives an email, need to identify specific domain(***@xyz.com) and if the domain is matching, need to replace the "from address" with random generated email address by the php code.

For the moment I have figure out that best way is to use the postfix(SMTP) and dovecot(pop3) mail servers, since postfix mail server is allowing to run php script after mail is received by the server. 
Because postfix smtp server allows to execute php code after receiving an email to server.

as research I have used below link explanation to start my work. 
https://thecodingmachine.io/triggering-a-php-script-when-your-postfix-server-receives-a-mail

But when I add that code as explained, I cannot restart the Postfix server.

I appreciate if anyone can support with a proper solution to my problem like any approach to get in to there.

Comment: Just out of interest: why would one want to alter received email messages? Apart from the legal implications (I really _hope_ this targets only messages sent to _you_), what good does that do? The "from" specified in email messages can be set to whatever you want anyway when sending an email, so it does carry any reliable information anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the update.
But the client needs are depend on his business. That's what customer wants anyway. Basically he wants to hide the sender information by replacing the from email address with another. and then when the receiver replies for that email, again server need to pick the correct email address from the DB and replace Random address with the actual email.

I know this is bit tricky, but I need to get this done somehow.

Comment: Sounds like a reseller portal, which is fine. But those do not use email servers for that purpose. Instead the email is received by the service, read, and the content is re-sent from the service with an own, internal, database-held sender address. Then, when receiving back a message addressed to that address the service looks up the original sender and again relays, so resends the message. No need to fiddle with the actual content. And once more the warning: altering messages can carry legal consequences, be it a customer of your requesting that or not.